# How to correctly link static library build and installed previously

Tags: cmake, static-linking

There is a static library called revolta which is being built and then installed into a sysroot:

```
set( CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX <path to sysroot> )

# ReVolta c++ library name
set( TARGET_LIBREVOLTA "revolta" )

add_library( ${TARGET_LIBREVOLTA} STATIC )

target_include_directories( ${TARGET_LIBREVOLTA}
PUBLIC
    # Once the librevolta targets are being exported, this include directory in which the lib is installed is used
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include>
PRIVATE
    # Include directory used privately just to build the library itself
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}>
)

target_sources( ${TARGET_LIBREVOLTA}
PUBLIC 
    ...
)
```

Later then once the librevolta is built, it is installed into the sys root using:

```
# Install all the revolta headers into include directory and copy the built library
install( TARGETS ${TARGET_LIBREVOLTA} EXPORT ${TARGET_LIBREVOLTA}
    FILE_SET HEADERS    DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include"
    ARCHIVE             DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib"
)
```

and the connected custom command:

```
# Once the librevolta is built, install it to the sysroot as specified by 'install()' commands
add_custom_command( TARGET ${TARGET_LIBREVOLTA} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ARGS --install . )
```

So far so good. This works as intended, once CMake builds the "`revolta`" target, it is built and installed into the sysroot as installed using the `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}`.

My problem is once I try to add the target as the linked one in other lib/executable, it includes somehow automatically the librevolta source path into includes and links the library using the relative path in the build directory rather than the one installed into sysroot as performed in the step right after the librevolta build.

Some other lib/executable:

```
target_link_libraries( ${APP_EXECUTABLE}
PRIVATE
    revolta
)
```

Once being built, the include path `-I/home/martin/git/revolta/source/librevolta` is added (the source location) even though it is stated as PRIVATE in the snipped above:

```
PRIVATE
        # Include directory used privately just to build the library itself
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}>
```

and only the `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include` is made public...

Additionally, the library is taken from the build tree rather than from the location where it is installed:

```
../../librevolta/librevolta.a
```

instead of

```
/home/martin/git/revolta/sysroot/lib/librevolta.a
```

Could you please advice me how to correctly set the `revolta` target the way it correctly uses its sources for building itself but once used elsewhere it provides the sysroot installed headers and built library from the same location (respecting the standard locations)?

**HINT**: I also tried to remove the revolta target from the app completely, specifying only to use the sys root (gcc option `--sysroot=/home/martin/git/revolta/sysroot`), it works fine correct headers and lib is used BUT once the `librevolta` is not built and installed, the target is not run prior to app build as the dependency is not defined then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR: You need to do what's done here:

### [**How to create a ProjectConfig.cmake file**](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-to-create-a-ProjectConfig.cmake-file)

---

I see a few issues with these `CMakeLists.txt` files but they aren't related to your problem, because if I understand correctly what you are trying to do here, then there is no problem and it is used as intended.

Let me clarify:

- You have a library project that has it's own `CMakeLists.txt`, where you define the target `revolta`
- You have an executable project that has it's own `CMakeLists.txt`, where you define your executable target **and then you add the `revolta` target** via `add_subdirectory()` and `target_link_libraries(my_executable revolta)`

If that's the case then this is just bad:

```
# Once the librevolta is built, install it to the sysroot as specified by 'install()' commands
add_custom_command( TARGET ${TARGET_LIBREVOLTA} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ARGS --install . )
```

Forcing your build to automatically install this library is not the way to go, ever (you for example, need elevated privileges to build it in the first place, because of this command and that poses a security risk).

That being said what is happening is perfectly fine, because from the perspective of the `my_executable's CMakeLists.txt` you are still building i.e. you use the `BUILD_INTERFACE`. It is however something you do not want to do.

---

### What instead you want to do is:

Create generator files for a `revoltaConfig.cmake` file. For that I will refer you to this tutorial:

[**How to create a ProjectConfig.cmake file**](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-to-create-a-ProjectConfig.cmake-file)

After you create such file, i.e. after building and installing `revolta`. You will (in the process) also create a `revoltaConfig.cmake` file. Which helps you populate the `my_executable` project via `find_package(revolta)`.

The above is probably what you are interested in.

The **generator expressions** that you use to distinguish `BUILD_INTERFACE` and `INSTALL_INTERFACE` are mainly for header file locations (or other linked libraries). Because when you build the library the header files can have a different structure then when you install it (as you already know). And as such work perfectly fine in your `CMakeLists.txt`, because when you think about it:

- You don't want to copy changes to your library files (into the install directory) just to test ongoing development (features/bugfixes) in your executable.
- And during the build of the executable if your building another target then **IT IS NOT INSTALLED** but rather **BEING BUILT**. And you are most likely adding it as a built target.

So to sum up what would most likely happen here (using your old `CMakeLists.txt`) is that

- The moment you start building the executable which adds the target library as a dependency via `add_subdirectory` you are implicitly using `BUILD_INTERFACE` because you are building.
- If you were to then **install both the executable and the library** it would again use the correct install paths, i.e. you would then implicitly start using `INSTALL_INTERFACE`.

You could hack it without the projectConfig file using the same generator expressions by mixing them up, **but I don't recommend it**, because then the `CMakeLists.txt` wouldn't work without doing some weird steps beforehand.

Comment: Thank you Milan for your answer. Basically you have described the way I tried to follow previously but I faced the issue of performing the installation manually prior to building the app executable which uses the library. My problem mainly was the presence of revolts-config.cmake file in the expected install directory and the exported targets file included from package config file...